# В каких случаях использовать ByteArrayInputStream?

Tags: java

Например, для считывания байтов из файла используются `InputStream`, `BufferedReader` и т.д.
Встретил еще такой: `ByteArrayInputStream`.
В описании сказано:

> представляет входной поток, использующий в качестве источника данных
>   массив байтов

К каким файлам его применять?
Видел пример, в котором считывается обычный текстовый файл этим методом.
Как определить какой нужно использовать?
Вот пример:

```
String  getStringFromRawFile(Activity  activity) { 
    Resources r = activity.getResources();
    InputStream is = r.openRawResource(R.raw.test);
    String myText = convertStreamToString(is); 
    is.close();
    return  myText;
}

String  convertStreamToString(InputStream is) { 
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i = is.read();
    while (i != -1) 
    { 
        baos.write(i); 
        i = baos.read(); 
    } 
    return  baos.toString();
}
```

Comment: `BufferedReader` используется для буферизованного считывания символов, а `ByteArrayInputStream` - байт. Соответственно, `BufferedReader` имеет смысл использовать для текстовых файлов, а `ByteArrayInputStream` - для бинарных. При этом, конечно, никто не мешает считывать текстовый файл с помощью `ByteArrayInputStream`, и потом перегонять байты в символы, если это нужно.

Answer (score 4):

Не каждый поток предназначен для считывания из файла. Строго говоря, из файла считывает только `FileInputStream` - остальные потоки считывают откуда-то еще.

`ByteArrayInputStream` нужен, когда вам надо читать данные из массива байт. Обычно имеет смысл использовать его не сам по себе, а в комбинации с другим кодом, который умеет считывать из любого `InputStream`. К примеру, если у вас есть массив байт, в котором записан XML, и вам надо его распарсить, построив для него DOM - то `ByteArrayInputStream` будет именно тем, что вам нужно.

Comment: А что из себя представляет массив байтов? Или так обозначаются бинарные данные?

Comment: Пожалуйста, откройте учебник по Java и прочитайте главу про массивы.

Comment: Не, я как бы понимаю, что такой массив. И что такое массив байтов - byte[]. Интересует какие файлы представляют собой массив байтов. Вот я и уточнил насчет бинарных файлов.

Comment: Таких файлов нет. Повторяю. еще раз: **`ByteArrayInputStream` - это не файл.**

Answer (score 0):

ByteArrayInputStream так же как и ByteArrayOutputStream - симуляция реализации интерфейсов InputStream и OutputStream над массивом байт.

Самый простой пример, как вывести e.printStackTrace в строчку для дальнейшей обработки (ну предположим что так надо)?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(out));
String stack = out.toString();
```

И других способов, порой, нет.